# Get RAW value from input field - javascript/html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, encoding

I'm trying to get the raw value of an input html field:

HTML:

```
<input id="myInput"></input>
```

Let's assume user input is: \\

JS:
`$("#myInput").val()` --> \\\\

How can I get the exact user input?

Thanks

Comment: what's not exact about `.val()`?

Comment: `"\\\\" === String.raw\`\\\``...

Comment: @Sirko - it returns it doubled, not as a user mentioned.

Comment: @RoniKorenKurtberg — It doesn't.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/yamuseleji/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score -1):

[HTML <input> Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp)

> In HTML, the `<input>` tag has no end tag.

i.e. `</input>` isn't a thing...

[Wiki: Escape_character#JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#JavaScript)

> JavaScript uses the \ (backslash) as an escape character

`\` is the unescaped version of `\\`.

`\\` is the unescaped version of `\\\\`.

[According to the jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/val/), aside from

> **Note:** At present, using .val() on  elements strips carriage return characters from the browser-reported value.

`.val()` doesn't do any escaping/unescaping, so something else in your code is changing the value.